# How to set a listview column header to bold, in code

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a list view, which is used as a calendar display, with each column representing a day.
How can I set the column header to bold, in code?  Is it possible to do it directly, without bothering with defining styles, static resources, triggers etc?

I tried:

```
If TheDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or TheDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then Day01Column.SetValue(GridViewColumnHeader.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold) Else Day01Column.SetValue(GridViewColumnHeader.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal)
If TheDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or TheDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then Day02Column.SetValue(GridViewColumnHeader.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold) Else Day02Column.SetValue(GridViewColumnHeader.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal)
If TheDate.AddDays(2).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or TheDate.AddDays(2).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then Day03Column.SetValue(GridViewColumnHeader.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold) Else Day03Column.SetValue(GridViewColumnHeader.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal)
```

(and so on, for the whole month)
and then I tried:

```
Dim BoldStyle As New Style
BoldStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(Control.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold))
Dim NormalStyle As New Style
NormalStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(Control.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal))

If TheDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or TheDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then Day01Column.SetValue(GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyleProperty, BoldStyle) Else Day01Column.SetValue(GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyleProperty, NormalStyle)
If TheDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or TheDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then Day02Column.SetValue(GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyleProperty, BoldStyle) Else Day02Column.SetValue(GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyleProperty, NormalStyle)
If TheDate.AddDays(2).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or TheDate.AddDays(2).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then Day03Column.SetValue(GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyleProperty, BoldStyle) Else Day03Column.SetValue(GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyleProperty, NormalStyle)
```

Neither worked - the column headers seem resolutely non-bold.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm so fed up with WPF.  Everything is an order of magnitude more complicated.  Previously with WinForms, I could knock out little apps for myself in no time at all.  Now I spend weeks wrestling with XAML, databinding, commands, etc.  When things don't work, there are no error messages, Intellisense is only of minor help in the XAML, and the only benefit I get from all this is resolution-independent apps.

Edit:- I should add that I know this works:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderBoldStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderNormalStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    </Style>


If TheDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or TheDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then Day01Column.SetValue(GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyleProperty, Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("ColumnHeaderBoldStyle"))
```

But I believe I can only apply one style to an element, and since I also want to be able apply grey background to certain column headers, I think that would mean styles for grey only, bold only, grey + bold and neither.  And if I then wanted to set, say, the font colour, that would need 8 styles.  It doesn't scale well.
Surely there is a way to reach into the listview element from code and adjust individual bits of chrome?

Many thanks

Nick

Comment: *"I'm so fed up with WPF"* it kinda depends on what you want to build. Understand that design and styling should preferably be done in XAML not in the code behind. That's what WPF is all about, separating concerns. Design for the design team, code for the code team :-)

Comment: You need style triggers. BTW, WPF is awesome.

Comment: Hi Slugster.  I'm aware of style triggers.  However, as I said in my update, won't I need a separate style for each combination of effects?  Can't I just alter the individual setting somehow in code?

Comment: Rather than concentrating on setting a whole style, use triggers to set the values of individual properties. Once you have that going you can work out what to incorporate into a style.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I can do this from XAML as preparation:

```
<ListView.View>
   <GridView>
     <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="160">
     <GridViewColumn.Header>
       <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Name" Click="SortInterfaces_Click">Name</GridViewColumnHeader>
     </GridViewColumn.Header>
    </GridViewColumn>
```

and then in C# I switch font weights:

```
private void SortInterfaces_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  GridViewColumnHeader column = (sender as GridViewColumnHeader);
  if (column.Tag == null) return;
  column.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
  InterfaceSortChangeTo(column);
}
```

If WPF gives you pain, try not to stray from the default built-in functionality. For the functions that are in there, it's actually quite ok.